# Error while creating plugin using plugin builder in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I am building a QGIS plugin using qgis plugin builder 2.10.1. I am using Ubuntu 15.04. I had selected (/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins) path for the plugin to store in plugin builder, Its raising an error "**Directory not writable**". Am new to QGIS development in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you save it in another path?

Comment: Yes i can save.

Comment: When you save it to the other path, could you move it to `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins`?

Comment: Paste is disabled when i right click inside the path. I assume i can try moving the file inside the /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins by gksudo nautilus.

Comment: And also if the plugin is stored in some other path, the plugin builder shows result like "your plugin repository is /home/username/.qgis2/python/plugin. But i could not see nay folder ".qgi2" under /home/user.

Comment: this is a hidden folder, view it by CTRL+H while you're in the folder. and I guess if you ran QGIS with sudo, you could store it to `/usr/... `, otherwise this location needs root. as Joseph said, you can save it elsewhere and later move it.